# Android App Activity Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm having trouble opening an activity. In my first activity (activity_main), I have 3 buttons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    >

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:id="@+id/row1">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/buttonText1"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:id="@+id/row2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/buttonText2"
            android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:id="@+id/row3">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button03"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:hint="@string/buttonText3"
            android:onClick="browseExercises"
            android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I click on the 3rd button, and my second activity opens, which consists of two additional buttons.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    >

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:id="@+id/row1">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/alphabetical"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:onClick="Alphabetical"
            android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:id="@+id/row2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button99999"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/group"
            android:onClick="muscleGroups"
            android:padding="15dip" />

        </TableRow>



</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I click on either of these buttons, and I get an error telling me that "Unfortunately, Test_Project has stopped."

I already have an activity created for each of these two buttons, and everything for these two buttons are coded the exact same way as when I created my second activity, which opens just fine, and has buttons I can click on without causing any errors. I think I'm missing something fundamental here, it's like if I create too many activities, they aren't able to look back at my MainActivity.java file for the method that is supposed to open the next activity. Here is my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.test_project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void browseExercises(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrowseExercises.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void Alphabetical(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alphabetical.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void muscleGroups(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MuscleGroups.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test_project.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test_project.BrowseExercises"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_browse_exercises" 

            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test_project.MuscleGroups"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_muscle_groups" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test_project.Alphabetical"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alphabetical" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my logcat file:

```
04-20 13:46:57.632: W/dalvikvm(26747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dc42a0)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method muscleGroups(View) in the activity class com.example.test_project.BrowseExercises for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button99999'
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3587)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: muscleGroups [class android.view.View]
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3580)
04-20 13:46:57.639: E/AndroidRuntime(26747):    ... 11 more
04-20 13:46:59.202: I/Process(26747): Sending signal. PID: 26747 SIG: 9
```

Probably something pretty simple I'm just not aware of yet, but any help would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: Add your manifest file please

Comment: and the logcat please

Comment: Make sure you have mentioned all your activities in the application manifest file.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out... I assumed that everything needs to be kept in the MainActivity.java file, and didn't realize that when I create a new activity, not only is an XML file created, but an actual Java file for that activity is also created. When I clicked on the button, it was looking for the method in the corresponding java file, but not finding it because I has put them all in the MainActivity.java file, thinking that was like the "master" activity java file or something. Can someone with a better understanding of this maybe explain it a little better to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your comment I guess that you have not created JAVA files for other Activities.
For e.g. you must create `BrowseExercise.java` file in the directory where your main Activity lies. And then you need to define this Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
An easy way to do is by just clicking `+`(or something like that)  on left TOP corner , then Android , New Activity . Then you just have to select which type of activity you want to use .

Answer (score 0):

Have you made Java files for all your activity? Like if you are opening other activity it should fulfill following requirements:

1. It should be mention in manifest file with proper action
2. There should be one java file corresponding to that activity
3. Layout file should be defined or you should create layout via code
4. Intent should be properly declared.

If still problem exists please add more code of your intent calling and java files.